# Dealing with multiple python versions when python files have to use #!/bin/env python

Tags: python, shebang

I have this problem: 
 
`System A` runs Ubuntu and needs `Python 2.6` for a bunch of different things.
I Installed `Python 2.7` separately on `System A`
`System B` has `Python 2.7` natively.

I have a python script `BLAH` which says `#!/bin/env python` up top. 
Further down it executes another script `SIGH`, which up top also says: `#!/bin/env python`.

`BLAH` needs to run on either `System A` or `System B`, and it always needs to run `Python 2.7`

----
Part of my solution so far:
Have a wrapper script that first tries to see if `which python` is pointing to Python 2.7 
If that's okay then run `BLAH` with that path for python.
Else try `which python2.7` and use that path to run `BLAH` , and add that path to `env PATH`.

Problem with this solution is:

On `System A` (which has Python 2.7 installed separately)
When `BLAH` executes, it runs with Python 2.7 because of the wrapper script I wrote (okay so far..) 
When `BLAH` spawns `SIGH`, `SIGH` uses the shebang to find python in the path and then it's in trouble because it's looking for python in `env`'s `PATH` and it should be looking for `python2.7` in the path.

Is there a clean way of handling this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you import, then run SIGH from BLAH?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to add the path that you obtain from `which` to the `PATH` -- `which` actually will only search paths contained in `PATH`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a script that needs a certain python version, for example 2.7, I'd change the first line to

```
#!/bin/env python2.7
```

And then ensure that `python2.7` is on your path (you may have to add symlinks as appropriate).  In all the distributions I've used, these symlinks already exist.

(In fact, `python` is typically a symlink to `pythonX` which is a symlink to `pythonX.Y` or, in my case, `python -> python2 -> python2.7`. )

There's no need to hard-code a full path, as this may vary from distro to distro or box to box.

But since there should be no ambiguity for an executable on your path named `python2.7`, you should be fine without having to worry about hard-coding paths.

Alternatively, from within the first script, you could call the python interpreter directly, as in:

```
subprocess.Popen(['pythonX.Y', SCRIPT_NAME])
```

instead of

```
subprocess.Popen([SCRIPT_NAME])
```

**EDIT** As J.F. Sebastian notes in the comments, you could use [sys.executable](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable) in the first argument to ensure that the second script was passed to the same interpreter as the first.  e.g

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, SCRIPT_NAME])
```

As a side note, that may or may not be useful, you can access the version of the "current" Python interpreter *inside* the script by

```
import sys
print(sys.hexversion)
```

which may be useful to determine whether the correct interpreter is running.

Comment: @jedwards the certain shebang not working for, getting invalid path error in apache

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to first change the `#!/bin/env` to the `python2.7` path directly, for example: `#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7` will work.

In the case System A and B python2.7 path are in different places (which seems to be your case) you can always create a symlink like this:

```
ln -s /bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use virtualenv? It allows you to use any python version installed (besides other stuff)...

```
starenka /tmp % virtualenv test -ppython2.6
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.6
New python executable in test/bin/python2.6
Also creating executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools............................done.
Installing pip...............done.

starenka /tmp % source test/bin/activate

(test)starenka /tmp % which python
/tmp/test/bin/python

(test)starenka /tmp % python --version
Python 2.6.8

(test)starenka /tmp % echo '#!/usr/bin/env python\nimport sys; print sys.version_info' > test/test.py

(test)starenka /tmp % chmod +x test/test.py

(test)starenka /tmp % test/test.py
(2, 6, 8, 'final', 0)

starenka /tmp % virtualenv test7 -ppython2.7
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in test7/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in test7/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
starenka /tmp % source test7/bin/activate

(test7)starenka /tmp % which python
/tmp/test7/bin/python

(test7)starenka /tmp % python --version
Python 2.7.3rc2

(test7)starenka /tmp % echo '#!/usr/bin/env python\nimport sys; print sys.version_info' > test7/test.py

(test7)starenka /tmp % chmod +x test7/test.py

(test7)starenka /tmp % test7/test.py
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='candidate', serial=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Stupid and simple*

In the shell, if needed:

```
ln -s /path/to/your/python2.X /usr/local/bin/python2
```

In the Python script:

```
#!/bin/bash
"exec" "python2" "$0"
```

I've been through this kind of problems, and this solution solved most of the cases, and was easily portable from one system to another (you could face different paths between systems, different versions of the software...). First create a symlink to ensure that you will run the right version of Python (this is specially true now that you never now if Python3 is just Python), and then rely on the bash env. So, you don't change your script every time you target a system for a util-script that doesn't call for the hassle of a package.