# How to work with 2 diffrent python versions

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

I have two versions of python installed (used for diffrent projects)
as follows:
[image]

I have a script in the followin folder:

```
/home/user/Desktop/P
```

I want to set this folder/script to use Python 2.7.11 by default.
i used this line in the script:

```
#!/bin/env python2.7
```

as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320015
But it doesn't work. It still goes to `Python 2.7.6`
How can I set the folder to use `Python 2.7.11` for every script there?
Is it possible to just run it with "Python" keyword and it will know which version of python to select?

Edit:
This is what I did:
Followed this guide: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
cd my_project_folder
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Now it looks like:

[image]

however why when I do `Python --version`
i get:
[image]
I expected it to refer the "Python" to the current version since I call it from this folder.
Why it doesn't work?

Comment: I would expect you could write `#!/pathtobinary/python` at the top

Comment: Not a python expert (or coder) but also take a look at virtualenv https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: Use `which python2.7` to inspect the path. Add it to top as Jens suggested.

Comment: @JensMunk Why should I do that? `python` redirect to 2.7.6 I want it to redirect to Python 2.7.11, This is why I used `python2.7`

Comment: @knh170 python --> 2.7.6   pyhton2.7 --> 2.7.11 You can see it from the version in the image.

Comment: You could specify the full path to a binary, then this will be used (dirty hack).  Personally, I would create multiple symbolic links in `/usr/bin` e.g. python2.7.11 and python2.7.6 and use `env`.

Comment: @JensMunk see my edit

Comment: I tried the same here. It also does not work. I think it is due to the virtualenv is installed with your default python. I will try my approach without using a virtual environment, 2 secs

Comment: @java I have two versions of python installed. If I add a `#!/opt/anaconda2/bin/python` at the top of an executable python file, I use the anaconda distribution, if `#/bin/env python` I use the primary or default version of python

Comment: @JensMunk This doesn't make sence... it means that the Virtual Enviroument accutly useless... many thoulsends of users use it. I'm not familiar with your approch. My script isn't executable it's a py file which I run from command line.

Comment: I know, I tried your approach, which seems like the correct use of virtual environments and I see the same error here. My workaround is to add symbolic links, then `source whatever.py` or `./whatever.py` or `./python2.7.11` and `./python2.7.9` will work as aspected. Looking forward to see a solution using virtual environments - I never got that to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108074/discussion-between-jens-munk-and-java).