# Cannot install pyaudio in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyaudio

While I'm trying to run `pip install PyAudio`, I'm seeing the following error:

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o_0h_bmo/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o_0h_bmo/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8_ovxdkm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 21):

You just need to remove `libav-tools` from apt install and run this command again.

`!apt install libasound2-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg`

and then

`!pip install PyAudio`

You will be able to install it.

Comment: where i can remove libav-tools?

Comment: Just run the commands which I have shared. You will be able to install @AbdunNoorPolok

Comment: Yeah, It works, Successfully built pyaudio

Comment: It worked for up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're running the default Python (currently, version 3.7.10) on Colab. In that case, `PyAudio` is an old and possibly unmaintained package and there is no wheel for Python 3.7.

The official [documentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) says:

> Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official distributions
> of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. For those versions, both 32-bit and
> 64-bit wheels are available.

There are two ways you can solve this—

- Going with a different package that does similar things. Checkout [**Python Sound Device**](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice).
- Downgrade your Colab environment to Python 3.6. Check out the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168301/how-to-change-the-python-version-from-default-3-5-to-3-8-of-google-colab).

If I were you, I would go with the first option as you should be using the newer Python version anyway. Also, subjectively, Python Sound Device has the better API.