# AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'dist'

Tags: python, math, module, google-colaboratory

I have code that works well in local Jupiter Notebook. I try to run the same code in google colab but there I get an AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'dist'. The code below is couple of lines from my project

```
 import math
 distance = math.dist(x, y)
```

Update: the default version of python in google colab is 3.7.13

Comment: What Python version is this? `math.dist` is "new in version 3.8."

Answer (score 3):

Update: I found that the problem occurs because of version of python. The function dist was added to math module only since Python 3.8.

The colab successfully updated to 3.9.13

```
#install python 3.9
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.9

#change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 

#check python version
!python --version
#3.9.13
```

The code above I found on StackOverFlow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version)