# Updating version of python on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-poetry

I need to update the default python version in Google Colab to version 3.9 in order to install some packages via poetry. However, when I update python I seem to lose the ability to install anything at all. I'm updating python by following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version), which works in so far as giving me the version of python I need:

```
#install python 3.9
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.9

#change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2

#check python version
!python --version
# returns Python 3.9.13
```

However, when I then try to install poetry via `!pip3 install poetry` I get the following response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Curiously, when I try `!pip3 install poetry` before updating python it works. However, if I install poetry first, then update python, when I try to install the variopus packages I need via `!poetry install` I get a similar traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/poetry", line 5, in <module>
    from poetry.console import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry'
```

Long-story-short, I can't work out how I can get the version 3.9 of python in Colab AND poetry to work.

Comment: You need `apt install python3-pip`. Alternatively, install/use `pyenv` rather than apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to install pip with `!sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Then you might need the distutils lib `!sudo apt install python3.9-distutils`

Comment: Thanks - that gets me a little further along, but gives me another traceback error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'```

Comment: so try with !sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Comment: That seemed to give the same error. following the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025189/pip-is-not-working-importerror-no-module-named-pip-internal) though seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe because you installed and deleted it before installing pip again ?