# Google Colab, Joblib.load error: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'

Tags: python, scipy, google-colaboratory

I need to load a model that I locally developed using Python ver. 3.10 to Google Colab. However, when I tried loading the model, it returns a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'`. I tried using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version) to upgrade the Python version on Colab to 3.10, but it still won't work. Below is my code:

```
#install python 3.10
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.10

#change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 2

#check python version
!python --version
# Python 3.10.6
```

Then I tried loading the model from my Google Drive:

```
NoPoverty_model = joblib.load(open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Model/NoPoverty_model.sav", 'rb'))
# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: `from scipy import sparse`

Comment: Hi, I've tried both `import scipy` and `from scipy import sparse` but both of them returns the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'`. Any other ideas on how to solve this?