# After upgrading python version in Google Colab, can no longer import packages with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, google-colaboratory

After following the steps outlined here [How can I update Google Colab's Python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version/68658479#68658479), I can no longer import packages with either,
`!pip install <package name>`,
`!pip3.9 install <package name>`,
`!python3.9 -m pip install <package name>`

When I try to import the , I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<package name>'`

Any advice would be more than welcome.

Kind Rgds

Comment: Not all modules are available for any version of python... did you check that this package you want is available? Can you edit the question to include what the package name is? And what is the current python version?