# How to change Python version in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Currently Google Colab runs on python 3.7 version. But for my project I need to change it to at least 3.8 version. So I've tried with multiple solutions but none of them are actually updating the version.. Yes when I use `!python --version` I get new version, but in `sys.path` and `sys.version` are showing me older path as well as older python version..

```
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.9
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3    # 0 for latest version 3.9

!sudo apt-get install python3-pip
!sudo apt install python3.9-distutils
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip
!python3 -m pip --version
```

After all of these commands I get `pip 22.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)` and `Python 3.9.15` from running these 2 commands `!pip --version` and `!python --version`
But when I try to print sys.path and sys.version it's the same.. Also I've tried to append path to sys.path (removing all other paths for 3.7 and adding for 3.9) but still version is older one..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update Google Colab's Python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version)

Comment: @Axeltherabbit No, I already tried that and didn't work out for me

Comment: have you read the note he left at the end? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68658479/8340761

Comment: @Axeltherabbit Yes, but I don't know how to install everything, or to setup new environment