# How to downgrade python version to 3.9 in colab without creating virtual environments? [solution found]

Tags: google-colaboratory, python-3.9, python-3.10, downgrade

I'm trying to downgrade python to 3.9 in colab as its kernel is now set to 3.10 by default. I followed the steps in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version](https://stackoverflow.com) and successfully converted the Python version to 3.9.

However I tried the following commands ut still couldn't convert the `sys.version` to 3.9.

```
#install python 3.9 and dev utils
#you may not need all the dev libraries, but I haven't tested which aren't necessary.
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-distutils libpython3.9-dev

#change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2

#Check that it points at the right location
!python3 --version

# install pip
!curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
!python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall

#install colab's dependencies
!python3 -m pip install ipython ipython_genutils ipykernel jupyter_console prompt_toolkit httplib2 astor

# link to the old google package
!ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/google \
       /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/google

# There has got to be a better way to do this...but there's a bad import in some of the colab files
# IPython no longer exposes traitlets like this, it's a separate package now
!sed -i "s/from IPython.utils import traitlets as _traitlets/import traitlets as _traitlets/" /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/google/colab/*.py
!sed -i "s/from IPython.utils import traitlets/import traitlets/" /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/google/colab/*.py
```

The above code generates the this error:

```
sed: can't read /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/google/colab/*.py: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/google/colab/*.py: No such file or directory
```

I also tried `!sudo update-alternatives --config python3` and it still wouldn't work.

Most answers I coud get suggest that I link the python3.9 dist-packages to the old ones. However colab is forever reconnecting after I restart the kernel. The same problem applies to the alternative method which is creating a virtual environment using python 3.9. It just couldn't connect to the new kernel after I changed the **RunTime Type**.

Any thoughts on how it might e solved?

**Update: I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71511943 and it worked in colab. 2023/8/4**