# How can I downgrade Python in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, downgrade

I tried downgrading my python in Google Colab to 3.4 to install a package which requires an older version of python. However, the following code didn't seem to work.

This code seems to work:

```
!sudo apt-get update -y

!sudo apt-get install python3.4
```

However I get a problem with these lines:

```
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.3 1

!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.4 2
```

output

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/python3.3 doesn't exist
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/python3.4 doesn't exist
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version)

However, this only talks about updating Python, not downgrading it. Also the other explanations didn't work for me.

My current Python version 3.10.12.

Comment: Obligatory note that 3.3 and 3.4 are no longer supported. See: [Status of Python versions](https://devguide.python.org/versions/). I recognize your situation might require out of support platforms though.

Comment: can you try following the steps in this link? https://medium.com/the-owl/changing-the-python-version-on-google-colab-245fd510d3ae I think it's similar just that in your case you might need 3.4 instead of 3.8.

Comment: from your previous question, I do understand why you need this. I'd suggest you go back to the comments under my answer, someone made a suggested fix to it or maybe you can look for an alternative package to `guidedlda`. It's actually not a good idea to use abandoned packages that haven't been updated in a while. Wishing you the best.