# Colab notebook keeps crashing after trying to update to python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have a colab notebook with 2 cells:

**First Cell**

```
#check python version
import sys
print(sys.version)
!python3 --version
!python --version
```

**Second Cell**

```
import sys #for version checker
import os #for restart routine

if '3.11' in sys.version:
  print('You already have 3.11')
else:
  #install python 3.11 and dev utils
  #you may not need all the dev libraries, but I haven't tested which aren't necessary.
  !sudo apt-get update -y
  !sudo apt-get install python3.11 python3.11-dev python3.11-distutils libpython3.11-dev
  !sudo apt-get install python3.11-venv binfmt-support #recommended in install logs of the command above

  #change alternatives
  !sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 1
  !sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.11 2

  #install pip
  !curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.11
  !python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall

  #install colab's dependencies
  !python3 -m pip install setuptools ipython ipython_genutils ipykernel jupyter_console prompt_toolkit httplib2 astor

  #minor cleanup
  !sudo apt autoremove

  #link to the old google package
  !ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/google
  #this is just to verify if 3.10 folder was indeed created
  !ls /usr/local/lib/python3.11/

  #Be sure to restart the environment 
  os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

I got the second cell's code from [How can I update Google Colab's Python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657341/how-can-i-update-google-colabs-python-version).
After restarting, the new session's runtime will always crash no matter what, and I can't get colab to run on python 3.11, which I desperately need. Every code answer provided in the post doesn't work and my notebook always crashes after the restart

I tried to modify the packages I needed to install, but it does not work - the after restarting the session the kernel keeps crashing and I'm unable to get sys.version to be 3.11