# Google Colab upgraded python version to 3.10

Tags: installation, google-colaboratory, spacy, python-3.8, allennlp

I am trying to use google colab to use allennlp library 0.9.0. Recently Google colab upgraded its python version to 3.10. Using the fallback command (Google colab's official way to use previous python version) downgrades the python version to 3.9 but I still need python 3.8.

I tried below code snippet (from [how to change the python version from default 3.5 to 3.8 of google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168301/how-to-change-the-python-version-from-default-3-5-to-3-8-of-google-colab)) and it downgrades to python 3.8.10

[Python version changed to 3.8.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0IoB.png)

But while installing spacy version 2.1.9, I am having issue. I believe it is due to the building "srsly". Everything was working fine earlier when google colab didn't upgrade the python version.
Please help.

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting spacy==2.1.4
  Downloading spacy-2.1.4.tar.gz (29.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 29.8 MB 81.0 MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-3pfggbcu/overlay --no-warn-script-location -v --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/ -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.0.0.dev6 Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried installing different spacy version between 2.1.0 and 2.1.9 and none of the spacy was able to install on python